# Custom Serialization/De-serialization Issue

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

Given this XML element:

```
<SampleA>0</SampleA>
```

Why is `reader.HasValue` resolving to false when the element clearly has a value ("0")?

```
if (reader.HasValue)
    this.SampleA = Int32.Parse(reader.ReadElementString("SampleA"));
```

Is this the correct property to check for the above purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be because your reader is on another node.

You may want to try:

```
 if( reader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.LocalName == "SampleA") {
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between LocalName and Name? I see one is qualified and the other is the local name, what do these mean exactly?

Comment: AFAIK QualifiedName includes the namespace (Prefix:LocalName) whereas LocalName is just name. Hope this helps.